# Swing: save the current graphics

Tags: java, image, swing, graphics, save

I have SWing code that creates some graphics. I have a button `"Run Again"` which can re-create the graphics.

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {

                final GraphicsDemo_noborders_ML demo = new GraphicsDemo_noborders_ML();

                final JFrame jFrame = new JFrame();

                jFrame.setTitle("Latest Programic Art");
                jFrame.setSize(canvasW, canvasH);

                JButton save = new JButton("Save");
                JButton run = new JButton("Run Again");

                save.setBounds(50, 100, 100, 50);
                run.setBounds(50, 500, 100, 50);

                final JPanel panel = new JPanel();

                panel.add(save);
                panel.add(run);

                final JComponent canvas = new JComponent() {

                    @Override
                    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
                        demo.paint(g);
                    }
                };

                jFrame.getContentPane().add(canvas, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                jFrame.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);


                run.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
                        demo.paint(g);
                    }
                });

                save.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
                        chooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY);
                        chooser.showSaveDialog(null);

                        String location = chooser.getSelectedFile().toString();
                        demo.saveImageToLocalDisk(jFrame, location);
                    }
                });

                jFrame.setVisible(true);
                jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            }
        });
```

The save button is for saving current graphics as an image. However, when I save it doesn't save the current graphics, but, only the initial one.

The method that saves is provided below,

```
private void saveImageToLocalDisk(JFrame jFrame, String location) {

        BufferedImage image = null;

        try {

            Rectangle rectangle = jFrame.getBounds();
            image = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rectangle);

        } catch (AWTException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        Graphics2D graphics2D = image.createGraphics();
        jFrame.paint(graphics2D);

        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(location + "/Graphics.jpeg"));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("error");
        }
    }
```

How do I correct this?

Comment: If you need to see the paint method, please comment below.

Comment: The code you've posted give us no hint about, where is your problem. Please provide a [mcve] so we can also reproduce and debug it to find a solution, that is suitable for your case. Please don't post your entire code here, but rather create a small runnable class, that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: (1-) Why do you keep posting this old code??? You have been told the structure of your code is completely wrong. Once again you have another problem because of the poor structure. If you would follow the working example you have been given, there would be no problem. Not only that the code you posted is useless. You don't post the code showing how you recreate the image, You don't show the "saveImageToLocalDisk. Your code still has "setBounds()" statements even though you have been told they do nothing. Why should we keep trying to help when you don't listen to advice already given???

Comment: And note the answer below won't work because they haven't been following all your previous question. Its assumes you are creating a BufferedImage where you do your custom painting. But you are doing custom painting in a JCompoinent, so the solution will be different. We can't answer question unless we have all the information. Start with the code from the Swing custom painting tutorial. It is simple to understand and easier to modify. Learn the basics first before try more advanced features. Then you have simple code to post in the forum.

Comment: @camickr I apologize for posting it incorrectly. I don't have a lot of experience with Swing and working on a small app that I would like to complete soon as possible.  I updated the question with the `saveImageToLocalDisk` method.

Comment: You missed the first comment. We want to see an [mre]. We are not interested in your application. The point of the "MRE" is to simplify the code to make sure you understand the question you are asking and are using minimal code to demonstrate the problem. Note in the "MRE" provided by Sergiy below you can' copy/paste/compile/test a single Java source file. We are not concerned about you complete the app when it is convenient to you. We are concerned that the question is easy for us to understand. You take the time to make it easy for us to help you.

Comment: I for one will not help because you have made no effort to restructure you code. Poorly structure code will only keep causing problems as you try to add new functionality. For the 3rr or 4th time, the demo code from the Swing tutorial is the place to start for a better structure.

Comment: @camickr please, don't get upset. Sometimes people have not much time or have other priorities. However, I get where do you come from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example, how I would implement your app (recreate + save image).

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;

/**
 * <code>PaintDemo</code>.
 */
public class PaintDemo {

    private int recreateIndex = 1;

    private BufferedImage image;

    private final JLabel imageLabel = new JLabel();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new PaintDemo()::startUp);
    }

    private void startUp() {
        recreateImage();
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Paint app");
        frm.add(imageLabel);
        JPanel buttonBar = new JPanel();
        JButton recreate = new JButton("Recreate");
        recreate.addActionListener(e -> recreateImage());
        buttonBar.add(recreate);
        JButton save = new JButton("Save");
        save.addActionListener(e -> save());
        buttonBar.add(save);
        frm.add(buttonBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void recreateImage() {
        image = new BufferedImage(400, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g = image.createGraphics();
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(20, 30, 100, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
        g.drawOval(200, 150, 50, 50);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawString("Recreated image: " + recreateIndex++, 200, 250);
        imageLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
    }

    private void save() {
        JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();
        int result = chooser.showSaveDialog(imageLabel);
        if (result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            File f = chooser.getSelectedFile();
            try {
                ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", f);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was that I was passing the `JFrame` instead of the `JComponent` which owns the graphics. I corrected the code,

```
private void saveImageToLocalDisk(JComponent component, String location) {

        try {

            BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(component.getWidth(), component.getHeight(),
                    BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);

            Graphics graphics = image.getGraphics();
            paint(graphics);

            ImageIO.write(image, "jpeg", new File(location + "/Graphics.jpeg"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```